# Given a hexagon of side 2 and 25 points inside it,

Tags: geometry

Question -

Given a hexagon of side 2 and 25 points inside it, show that there are atleast 2 among them which are at most a unit apart..

My try -

I know pigeon hole principle will apply taking 8x3 =24 regions so that atleast one region will contain more than 1 points or atleast 2 points.....but i.am not able to draw these 24 regions so that distance apart is at most a unit
.... kindly give me hint...

Comment: If $a$ is really big, it should be easy to distribute points such that none of them are within $1$ of any other. Do you mean to say that the sides of the hexagon are $2$? And is the hexagon assumed to be regular?

Comment: No, in book it is written 2a and it is not mentioned that hexagon is regular or not....its just written hexagon

Comment: "A hexagon of side $2a$" : it must be a regular hexagon, because there's no way you specify one side and can draw the full hexagon.  And if $a$ can vary, then I make it very high and get a contradiction. Please clarify that $2a = 2$, then I think the question not only makes sense, but is very nice.

Comment: Yes,I think question has error ...I have edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hexagon can be decomposed into 6 equilateral triangles, and each equilateral triangle can be further decomposed into 4 smaller equilateral triangles. Can you finish from there?

Answer (score 1):

You can cover a regular hexagon of side $2$ with $19$ regions of diameter $1$ as in the picture 
[image: hegagon_cover]
So given $20$ points in a regular hexagon of side $2$ there are $2$ of them in the same region, and so at a distance at most $1$.

Note that we can place $19$ points in the hexagon so that the minimal distance between them is $1$. So we are not very far from the optimal.