# Can we place $18$ points in a regular hexagon of side $2$ such that the minimal distance between points is $>1$?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, combinatorial-geometry

> Can we place $18$ points in a regular hexagon of side $2$ such that the minimal distance between points is $>1$?

This a follow-up of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3563966/14-points-in-a-regular-hexagon-of-side-2).  In the answers provided for it there are shown solutions for $14$, $15$, $16$, and $17$ points. Also, we can place $19$ points so that the minimal distance between them is exactly $1$.

Thank you for your interest!

Comment: IIRC, it can be added that with $19$ points $>1$ is not possible (only $=1$)

Comment: Perhaps it helps to distinguish cases according to the number of points in the central hexagon of side length $1$? There are at most $5$ points in this region, and the remaining region is a hexagonal annulus. It seems impossible, but it seems that any proof will be a rather cumbersome exercise in elementary geometry.

Comment: Minor result; a configuration of $18$ points cannot contain all vertices of the regular hexagon of side $2$.

Comment: By gnawing off 17 shapes of diameter 1, I found that one point must lie within a comet-shaped thing of area $\approx 0.2$ (and diameter slightly $>1$). There are six symmetric copies of this comet and so I can conclude that there must be a point at most $0.2$ off the centre of the hexagon, or each "comet tail" must contain exactly one point. -- I did this in a geogebra session with *confusingly* many radius 1 circles, so I am not 100% sure about the exact sizes stated above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that we placed $18$ points in a regular hexagon of side $2$ such that the minimal distance between points is $2r$. It follows that we can pack $18$ circles of radius $r$ into a regular hexagon of side $2+\tfrac{2r}{\sqrt{3}}$, or $18$ unit circles into a regular hexagon of side $\tfrac 2r+\tfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$. But [the smallest known side of such a hexagon is $4+\tfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$](https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/cirinhex/). It follows $r\le \tfrac 12$.

I expect that an easy proof of the example optimality following from a partition of the hexagon into $17$ pieces of diameter at most $1$ is impossible. I guess that a proof of the example optimality is hard.

One of approaches to the proof, [started](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3565251/can-we-place-18-points-in-a-regular-hexagon-of-side-2-such-that-the-minimal/3569237?noredirect=1#comment7331563_3565251) by Hagen von Eitzen is to localize positions of points in a solution. This approach was inductively used to solve a similar problem below. I proposed it at the final stage of All-Ukrainian student mathematical olympiad in 2001. No participants achieved an advance solving the problem. Also I found this problem (without a solution) in a book “How nonstandard problems are solved” by  A. Ya. Kanel'-Belov and A. K. Koval'dgi, (Moskow, MCNMO, 1997, in Russian), see Problem 15 at p. 49.

> In a cube $Q$ with an edge $1$ are placed $8$ points. Whether always among them there exist two points placed at distance at most $1$?

First we remark that a maximal distance from a polyhedron to a point outside it can be reached in one of vertices of the polyhedron. Now let $x_1,\dots, x_8\in Q$. Suppose that all distances between points are greater than $1.$ Then in every of $8$ closed cubes at the picture can be placed at most one point $x_i.$ Without loss of generality we can suppose that $x_1\in M_1.$ If $x_1=(x_1^1,x_1^2,x_1^3),$ then $x_1\le a_1,$ where $|(1,1/2,1/2)-(a_1,0,0)|=1,$ thus $a_1=1-1/\sqrt{2}<1/2$ (otherwise for all $i\in\{1,\dots,4\}$ we have $|A_i-x_1|<1$ and therefore there exists $j\ne 1$ such that $|x_i-x_j|<1$). We can similarly prove that $x_1^2\le a_1,x_1^3\le a_1.$ Thus, a point $x_1$ is in cube $M'_1$ with an edge $a_1.$ Similar arguments can be used for all other $x_i$. Assume that it is already proved that all points $x_i$ have to be in small cubes with an edge $a_n.$ Similarly to the previous we can prove, that all of them must be in small cubes with edge $a_{n+1},$ where $|(1,a_n,a_n)-(a_{n+1},0,0)|=1,$ thus $2a_n^2+a^2_{n+1}-2a_{n+1}=0$. If $a_{n+1}>a_n,$ then $3a_{n+1}^2-2a_{n+1}>0$ and therefore $a_{n+1}>2/3,$ that is impossible, because $a_{n+1}\le a_1<1/2.$ Thus a sequence $\{a_n\}$ has a limit $a$, and $3a^2-2a=0.$ Hence $a=0.$  Thus all points are placed in vertices of the cube $S,$ a contradiction.

[image]

Comment: "But the smallest **known** side ...".  Does this signify that a denser packing has been proven to be impossible, or does this signify that no denser packing has as yet been discovered?

Comment: So it seems the answer is no.  Great idea to connect it with packing of disks inside hexagons.

Comment: However, can you prove the above fact? The idea is good to show that we cannot place $19$ points, since that would show a more dense packing of disks in the plane. That is not possible ( classic result, but not easy to prove).

Comment: @orangeskid I updated an answer.

Comment: Interesting!  Now, maybe there is a similar solution for the hexagon? How about $19$ points? It should follow from other results, but even this one seems difficult.

Comment: The first link is dead, unfortunately.